# Duplicate and incorrect print on BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a script that tries to parse from eBay to csv, but when I when run my script it turns out a weird result. I'm just trying to say in the code if the data is empty, leave the cell as empty. I suspect my Elif usage.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

URL='https://www.ebay.com/b/Makeup-Products/31786/bn_1865570' #'https://www.ebay.com/b/Makeup-Products/31786/bn_1865570' #https://www.ebay.com/b/Eye-Makeup/172020/bn_1880663
response=requests.get(URL)
soup= BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
columns=["Name","Price","Rating","Location"]
#Product features
main_table=soup.find('ul',attrs={'class':'b-list__items_nofooter'})
item_boxes=main_table.find_all('div',attrs={'class':'s-item__info clearfix'})
item = item_boxes[0]

df=pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

for item in item_boxes:

    item_name = item.findAll('h3')
    try:
       item_name_row = item_name[0].text.replace('\n','')
    except:
       item_name = "N/A"


    item_price = item.find_all('span',{'class':'s-item__price'})
    try:
       item_price_row = item_price[0].text.replace('\n','')
    except:
       item_price_row = "N/A"      

    try:
       item_rating = item.findAll('div',{'class':'s-item__reviews'})[0].div
       item_rating_row = item_rating.text
    except:
       item_rating_row = None

    try:
       item_location = item_location = item.find_all('span',{'class':'s-item__location s-item__itemLocation'})[0]
       item_location_row = item_location.text
    except:
       item_location_row = None   

    row = [ item_name_row, item_price_row, item_rating_row, item_location_row ]
    df =df.append(pd.Series(row,index=columns),ignore_index=True)
    df.to_csv('ebay5.csv', index=False)


    if item_rating != None:

      row = [item_name[0].text.replace('\n','') for name in item_name] + [item_price[0].text.replace('\n','') for price in item_price] + [item_rating.text.replace('\n','') for rating in item_rating] + [item_location_row[0].replace('\n','') for location in item_location]

    elif item_location != None:

      row = [item_name[0].text.replace('\n','') for name in item_name] + [item_price[0].text.replace('\n','') for price in item_price] + [item_rating.text.replace('\n','') for rating in item_rating] + [item_location_row[0].replace('\n','') for location in item_location]
    else: 
      row = [ item_name[0].text.replace('\n','') for name in item_name] + [item_price[0].text.replace('\n','') for price in item_price] + [item_rating] + [item_location_row]
    df =df.append(pd.Series(row,index=columns),ignore_index=True)

df.to_csv('ebay5.csv', index=False)
```

It takes the data duplicate and takes only "F" in the second line.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

During the loop you call  **twice**

```
df = df.append(pd.Series(row, index=columns), ignore_index=True)
```

This is why you get double records.

Before the second call you modify the entry. This is why you get this output.

Answer (score 0):

why don't just comment out some code?

```
...
    df =df.append(pd.Series(row,index=columns),ignore_index=True)
    # df.to_csv('ebay5.csv', index=False)

    """
    if item_rating != None:

      row = [item_name[0].text.replace('\n','') for name in item_name] + [item_price[0].text.replace('\n','') for price in item_price] + [item_rating.text.replace('\n','') for rating in item_rating] + [item_location_row[0].replace('\n','') for location in item_location]

    elif item_location != None:

      row = [item_name[0].text.replace('\n','') for name in item_name] + [item_price[0].text.replace('\n','') for price in item_price] + [item_rating.text.replace('\n','') for rating in item_rating] + [item_location_row[0].replace('\n','') for location in item_location]
    else: 
      row = [ item_name[0].text.replace('\n','') for name in item_name] + [item_price[0].text.replace('\n','') for price in item_price] + [item_rating] + [item_location_row]
    df =df.append(pd.Series(row,index=columns),ignore_index=True)
    """
df.to_csv('ebay5.csv', index=False)
```

the rest of the code would work fine.

---

As per your comment, here are some errors that I found. Hope we can learn and improve together.

```
if item_rating != None:

      row = [item_name[0].text.replace('\n','') for name in item_name] + [item_price[0].text.replace('\n','') for price in item_price] + [item_rating.text.replace('\n','') for rating in item_rating] + [item_location_row[0].replace('\n','') for location in item_location]
```

itme_location_row is already a string, so you get "F" in the duplicated row in the location. Just don't get confuse of item_location and item_location_row.

you checked the None value of item_rating after you had appended the item, that is the reason you got two items when the item_rating is None. actually you will get more duplicated items if fields in other column are None.

if you really what to check the value and make some adjustment, do the if statement before you append the item.

call df.to_csv() outside of for loop once would be OK, don't do it in the for loop.

Comment: Ok bud I will shrink it in the next time, do you have any suggestion for error.